# Running a C# async method via COM from single threaded programming language

Tags: c#, com, async-await

We have a system running in a single threaded language (DataFlex), and make calls to C# code via COM. One such call takes multiple seconds to finish, and it would be nice to be able to let the C# method finish in the background without blocking the UI.

My first attempt, though, did not finish in the background - AsyncDbLoad seemingly had to complete its work before returning control to DataFlex.

```
  private async Task DbLoad()
  {
     LongRunningMethod();
  }

  public async Task AsyncDbLoad()
  {
     await DbLoad();
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to do this using async-await? It not, what should I do?

Comment: What version of dataflex are you using?

Comment: throwing `async Task` on a method by itself does nothing. you must have a `await` in your function too to get actual async behavior..

Comment: @AlexDev I tested this in version 15.1, but it should be the same on version 19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this version of DataFlex but I don't think using async await will help you. I would split it into 2 requests:

1: `int StartDbLoad()`: initiates the operation, returns an operation id.

2: `Result CheckResult(int operationId)`: checks if a result is available and retrieves it.

On the C# side you can use a `Task` to process the request in a separate thread and keep the result in a `Dictionary<int, Result>`.
Then you have to use any features available in DataFlex to poll for the result while keeping the UI responsive, such as a Timer.

Comment: I tried using Task.Run(() => { LongRunningMethod(); });        This works!